# How to vectorize an operation that uses previous values?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, back-testing

I want to do something like this:

`df['indicator'] = df.at[x-1] + df.at[x-2]`

or

`df['indicator'] = df.at[x-1] > df.at[x-2]`

I guess edge cases would be taken care of automatically, e.g. skip the first few rows.

Comment: `df.at` returns [an indexer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html), never a column even if there is one named `'at'`. To access a column named `'at'`, you must use `df['at']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should give you what you need. The first two rows for your `indicator` column will be automatically filled with 'NaN'.

`df['indicator'] = df.at.shift(1) + df.at.shift(2)`

For example, if we had the following dataframe:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-06-01','2017-06-02','2017-06-03',
                         '2017-06-04','2017-06-05','2017-06-06'],
                 'count'    :[10,15,17,5,3,7]})


          date     at
0   2017-06-01     10
1   2017-06-02     15
2   2017-06-03     17
3   2017-06-04      5
4   2017-06-05      3
5   2017-06-06      7
```

Then running this line will give the below result:

```
df['indicator'] = df.at.shift(1) + df.at.shift(2)

          date  at   indicator
0   2017-06-01  10         NaN
1   2017-06-02  15         NaN
2   2017-06-03  17        25.0
3   2017-06-04   5        32.0
4   2017-06-05   3        22.0
5   2017-06-06   7         8.0
```